# UIWebView custom UIActionSheet menu when long press on a link

Tags: ios, ios8, uiwebview, uiactionsheet

I'm implementing a custom menu when long press on a link on UIWebView.

To prevent iOS default menu, I'm using:

```
-webkit-touch-callout:'none'
```

Everything work fine in iOS 6, 7: my custom menu is shown instead of UIWebView default. But in iOS 8, a strange behavior happen.

In iOS 8, after my own menu is shown, I release touch, and the link's being load in UIWebView.

I subclass UIWindow, override sendEvent: and see the different:

- In iOS 6, 7: after my own menu shown, a touchcancel was sent.
- In iOS 8: nothing happen. But when I release touch, a touchend was
  sent and trigger link click.

I tried trigger touchcancel from javascript when my menu is begin shown, but no luck.

Is there any workaround for this situation?

Comment: try this: https://github.com/theniceboy/HoldToSaveImage

Comment: David, I tried your project and long-pressed on the yellow backpack as instructed on the readme, but I had no luck to see the customized alert message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might be concerned in future, I managed to overcome this situation by a tricky hack:

```
CGPoint currentOffset = webview.scrollView.contentOffset;
[webview.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(currentOffset.x, currentOffset.y +1) animated:NO];
[webview.scrollView setContentOffset:currentOffset animated:NO];
```

Comment: Out of the many approaches out there to keep the tap from occurring when replacing the long press gesture, this is the only one that works.